# Evaluate the indefinite algebraic integral $\int\frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to calculate $$I=\int\dfrac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$$

In my textbook, they advise us to put $x-1=\dfrac{1}{t}$, but I don't see how this helps. We will then have $$I=\int\dfrac{d\frac{1}{t}}{\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{t})^2+1+\frac{1}{t}+1}}=\int\dfrac{d\frac{1}{t}}{\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{(\frac{1}{t}+\frac32)^2+\frac34}}$$

How is this useful? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying gives (assuming $t > 0$, hence $x > 1$) that
$$I = -\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{3 t^2 + 3 t + 1}} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1 + u^2}}.$$ (If $t < 0$, we simply pick up an additional $-$ sign.)

> The second equality follows from substituting $t = \frac12\left(\frac1{\sqrt 3} u - 1\right)$.

Another option is the apply the Euler Substitution of the First Kind, $\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} = x + s$, to the original integral in $x$, which rationalizes it, after which the affine transformation $s = \sqrt 3 y - 1$ puts it in a standard form.
$$I = 2 \int \frac{ds}{s^2 + 2 s - 2} = -\frac2{\sqrt 3} \int \frac{dy}{1 - y^2} .$$ We can then proceed as usual.

Comment: What's the idea to substitute $t$ as given?

Comment: Do you mean, why would someone think to substitute $x - 1 = \frac1t$ in the first place?

Comment: Yes!...............

Comment: And how did you think to substitute $t=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}u-1\right)$?

Comment: Well, substituting $v = x - 1$ makes one of the factors of the denominator of the integrand a little simpler without complicating the integral otherwise, giving $$\int \frac{dv}{v \sqrt{v^2 + 3 v + v}}, $$ as in the first step of the alternative method in my answer. The substitution $t = \frac1v$ effectively eliminates a factor of $v$ from the denominator, setting up the substitution $t = \frac12 \left(\frac1{\sqrt 3} u - 1\right)$, which really just amounts to completing the square of the quadratic under the radical, itself the standard method at that point.

Comment: Okay, I got it why we put $x-1=\dfrac{1}{t}$, but then what I don't understand is why you decided to put $t=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}u-1\right)$. It't not still not clear for me at all.

Comment: I think I got it. But why can we consider that $t$ is positive though?

Comment: The idea is that we want to transform the expression $\sqrt{3 t^2 + 3 t + 1}$ into something that makes the integral easier to deal with. Since the discriminant of $3 t^2 + 3 t + 1$ polynomial is $-3 < 0$, some affine substitution $t = a u + b$ will put it in the standard form $1 + u^2$, and substituting that formula and solving for $a, b$ gives the coefficients.

Comment: If I got it right, the integral should be $-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}\ln(\sqrt{3}t+\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}+\sqrt{3t^2+3t+1})+C$. Actually the brackets should be absolute value.

Comment: But now substituting $t=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$ will be a huge mess I think.

Comment: It's not so bad, especially if we use the inverse hyperbolic sine function, since $\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1 + u^2}} = \operatorname{arsinh} u + C$. In the end I get $I = \frac1{\sqrt 3} \operatorname{arsinh} \left(\sqrt 3 \frac{1 + x}{1 - x}\right) + C$.

Comment: Following the idea you gave me here, I tried to solve a previous problem I was not able to finish before. The integral is $$\dfrac{dx}{(x+1)^3\sqrt{x^2+3x+2}}$$ I suppose the idea is similar so let $x+1=\dfrac{1}{t}$. After some simplification I arrive at $$-\int\dfrac{t^2dt}{\sqrt{1+t}}$$ Is this possible to integrate, or have I not understood the idea correctly? Thank you for your assistance! I really appreciate it.

Comment: And I question that arose in me but I wasn't able to answer myself. Why can we consider $t$ is posivite?

Comment: That's what I get for your new integral, too, but that would better be posted as its own question. To evaluate, substitute $u = 1 + t$.

Comment: As for positivity of $t$, we can't assume that, though on any interval whether the integrand is defined, the sign of $t$ is the same. My answer implicitly assumes $t > 0$, i.e., $x > 1$, but handling the negative case is, as usual, just a matter of inserting the appropriate sign. If you have more questions, please move this discussion to a chat room (just click the below link).

Comment: Did you mean to put $u=\sqrt{1+t}$? Sorry, but I can't see the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151234/discussion-between-travis-willse-and-saq).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid worrying about signs pulling the variable out of square-root, integrate instead with $$g(t)=\frac{ 3(1+\frac12 t)}{\sqrt{t^2+3t+3}}\>\implies 
g’(t)= \frac{g^2(t)-3}{t \sqrt{t^2+3t+3}}
$$
Then
$$\int \frac1{t \sqrt{t^2+3t+3}}dt= \int\frac{g’(t)}{g^2(t)-3}dt=-\frac1{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\frac{g(t)}{\sqrt3}+C
$$
which is valid for all domain $t$.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of $(x-1)$, we let $y=\frac{1}{x-1}$ and get
$$
I=\int \frac{d x}{(x-1) \sqrt{x^2+x+1}}=-\int \frac{d y}{\sqrt{3 y^2+3 y+1}}= -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \int \frac{d y}{\sqrt{(2 y+1)^2+\frac{1}{3}}}
$$
Letting $2 y+1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sinh \theta$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\frac{\sinh ^{-1}(\sqrt{3}(2 y+1))}{\sqrt{3}}+C \\
& =-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}(x+1)}{x-1}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$